# Yarn start fails with Unexpected identifier without details

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to start up a react app. After cloning the code from github, running yarn install I ran yarn start and got the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ cross-env HTTPS=true react-scripts start
Unexpected identifier
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The authors of the app don't know what might be wrong (it's working for them). I tried creating another app with create react app and that started up fine for me. I am not sure where to start looking as there is no indication as to where the "unexpected identifier" might be located or what it might be. Any ideas on what I might want to check or try? I am on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually. I tried running build and it failed on syntax error in one of the .js files (a missing comma). Once that was fixed the start ran too. If the start command returned the same informative error the build did it would have saved me hours :)